# multiple checks for file extension

Tags: c#, .net

I have property which holds filenameOnly without extension.

```
string fileNameOnly = "myFileName";
```

now I want to perform multiple checks on selected location for example `c:\` for existed filename+fileextension `(.jpg, .png, .gif, .bmp)`

so, if `c:\myFileName.jpg` exist than assign that value to `string filename="myFileName.jpg"` variable.

what is the best and quickest way to do this?

Comment: You could search for c:\myFileName.*, get the extension of the results, see if it's in your list, assign it to the variable. HD read is slow, the goal should first be to limit HD read.

Comment: noting that could have an array of results, of course.

Comment: I hate those questions (**what is the best and quickest way to do this?**) when people doesn't post any code showing his work so far and in fact is  ready to accept **any way** working.

Comment: What if `myfilename.bmp` and `myfilename.png` both exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this to get an array of files that fit your pattern:

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(
    DirectoryPath, 
    String.Format("{0}.*", fileNameOnly));
```